# DataFormatString doesn't work for some dates

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, date-format

I'm using these attributes for one of my property:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

As you can see I specified the date format string this way: `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}`.

**View**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="StartDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I post the form to server with this date: `17/12/2016` the `StartDate` gets null. Any idea?